# Run Python code on GPUs from Java

Tags: java, python, parallel-processing, opencl

I am currently working on a project in java, that should run python tasks(small machine learning tasks) on several GPUs. Java should take a task and try to parallel it.

I know I could use OpenCL\CUDA to do tasks on GPUs, and I could use several libraries to run Python code in Java.

The only way I see now is writing Python code using PyCUDA and just run it from Java. But I don't sure if it's possible to parallel Python code on GPUs through Java. Cause just running script isn't the same as choosing particularly vector and matrix operations and run them on GPUs effectively.

Is there any libraries to do that or is it impossible?

Comment: PyCUDA does not allow Python code to be run on GPUs

Comment: Theano then, that's not the the issue I think. The problem is to run Python small machine learning tasks in Java on GPUs through CUDA\OpenCL.

Comment: You can't run Java on GPUs either

Comment: I maybe misunderstand it..
I could run matrix operation on GPU from Java using CUDA, right?

Comment: If you have Java bindings to a linear algebra library which did what you want, then yes. Or if you have written your own CUDA code. But otherwise no.

Comment: Okay, so there is no way to automatically build bindings from Python code to the library(Aparapi for example)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166959/discussion-between-xerocry-and-talonmies).

Comment: There are tools to generate Cuda from msil (e.g. Hybridizer - note: we develop that tool) , and you may convert Java byte code to msil using ikvm for example. Hence, you may run something expressed in Java on the GPU.

Answer (score 2):

With TornadoVM [1], you can write Java code to be offloaded to GPUs via OpenCL and/or CUDA PTX. And the Java code can be invoked from any PL on top of GraalVM, including Python, Javascript, R, etc [2, 3].

- [1] https://github.com/beehive-lab/TornadoVM
- [2] https://github.com/jjfumero/qconlondon2020-tornadovm/tree/master/nodejs
- [3] https://github.com/jjfumero/nyjavasig-tornadovm-2021/blob/master/python/mxmWithTornadoVM.py